# 404 error with worklight project console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I'm using worklight 6.1 with oracle Java 7 and eclipse kelper SR1.  After creating the worklight development server and creating a new worklight project, I build and deploy the project to the worklight server.  It deploys successfully.  However when I go to the URL it provides for the console of the project (http:// localhost:10080/Project) I get a 404 error.

This was not an issue when I was using v6.1, however after I upgraded to v6.2, is when the error occured.  I've tried deleting eclipse and the workspace and reinstalling everything and still get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue when upgrading an existing Worklight Studio v6.1 installation to v6.2. There is no workaround.

You need to use a fresh copy of Eclipse and install Worklight Studio v6.2 on it (with a fresh workspace for this instance of Eclipse). It should then work.

Additionally I am not sure from your writing how you are opening the console, but make sure you are right-clicking on the Worklight project icon and select to open the Worklight Console from there.

If the error still happens, open the Console view in Eclipse > Worklight Development Server console and see if there are any errors. Then, add them to your question.

Comment: I had a completely fresh version of worklight.  However it seemed to work by opening the console through right clicking the project in eclipse.  It seemed to be some sort of permissions issue.  When I went to the console through right clicking, it did some type of logging in with credentials.  Not sure if related or not.